# Why is the constructor with the interface parameter being used instead of the constructor with the most derived parameter type?

Tags: c#, polymorphism

I encountered a problem in our code where certain information was disappearing. I did find a fix for it, but I don't quite understand this behavior. I've made an example for the sake of simplicity:

**The common interface**

```
public interface IFruit
{
    Color Color { get; set; }
}
```

**The 2 Derived classes:**

```
public class Apple : IFruit
{
    public int Radius { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public Apple(IFruit fruit)
    {
        Color = fruit.Color;
    }

    public Apple(Apple apple)
    {
        Color = apple.Color;
        Radius = apple.Radius;
    }

    public Apple(Color color, int radius)
    {
        Color = color;
        Radius = radius;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"I'm a {Color.ToString()} apple with a radius of {Radius}cm";
    }
}

public class Banana : IFruit
{
    public int Length { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public Banana(IFruit fruit)
    {
        Color = fruit.Color;

    }

    public Banana(Banana banana)
    {
        Color = banana.Color;
        Length = banana.Length;
    }

    public Banana(Color color, int lenght)
    {
        Color = color;
        Length = Length;
    }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"I'm a {Color.ToString()} banana with a length of {Length}cm";
    }
}
```

**The test code:**

```
[TestClass]
public class FruitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void WhichConstructorIsUsed()
    {
        var fruits = new List<IFruit>();
        fruits.Add(new Apple(Colors.Red, 5));
        fruits.Add(new Banana(Colors.Yellow, 20));

        var clonedFruits = fruits.Select(f => new Apple(f));

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", clonedFruits));
    }
}
```

**Output**

> I'm a Red apple with a radius of 0cm
>
> I'm a Yellow apple with a radius of 0cm

**What I do not understand**

Notice that the red apple loses it's radius value. I understand that the banana loses it's information, but I do not understand why, for the Apple instance, the constructor Apple(IFruit fruit) is being used instead of the Apple(Apple apple) constructor. It is an apple, it's just in a typed list of the basetype.

I expected the Banana instance to use the more generic constructor, but not the Apple instance.

Comment: f is of type `IFruit` as you specified in your list `List<IFruit>`. So of course the respective constructor is used

Comment: Exactly as @ErikT. said - the compiler chooses the constructor to call at compile time. At compile time, all it knows is that you're looping through a list of `IFruit`, and calling `new Apple(fruit)`. Since each `fruit` is an `IFruit`, it chooses the `Apple(IFruit)` constructor.

Comment: @canton7 Ah I see. Knowing that this is decided at compile time calrified it to me. I expected it to figure out what the most fitting type was at run time. Thank you for the explanation. Too bad I can't mark a comment as anwer.

Comment: The compiler always picks the method to call at compile-time (except when `dynamic` is involved). Since Dan Gardner already has an answer which says pretty much exactly this, I don't want to add another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the point you retrieve `f` from the list it is of type `IFruit` as you declared your list as `List<IFruit>`. When you call `f => new Apple(f)` you are calling Apples constructor with an `IFruit` and not a concrete type.

If you were to explicitly cast the `Apple` from the list you would get full access to all the concrete types properties.